# ruby on rails- nested attributes for 'has_one' relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some help concerning nested attributes in models with 'has_one' relationship.

Model Survey has 1 question
Model Question has 1 answer

How do i build the 'answer' in the code below

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
   @survey.build_question # build one question
    @survey.question.answer.build #this part is not working

end
```

Please can anybody tell me how to build the answer  as the code "@survey.question.answer.build" is not correct.

Many many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must build the answer on the newly created `Question` instance since it's not yet been saved.

```
@survey = Survey.new
@question = @survey.build_question
@answer = @question.build_answer
# ... at some point in the future
@survey.save
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the suggestion but '@survey.question.build' does not seem to work when there is a 'has_one' relationship between the models. I have to use the following format '@survey.build_question' otherwise i get the following error message 'undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: If i am to use --- @survey = Survey.new
@question = @survey.build_question
@answer = @question.answer.build, then how do i tackle the @answer part ?? :(

Comment: I mean '@answer = @question.answer.build' is now giving me the following error message 'undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: Are you sure `Question` and `Answer` are in a `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationship?  Can you edit your question to paste question.rb and answer.rb?

Comment: I got it --it should be '@answer = @question.build_answer'

Comment: Question and Answer are in a has_one/belongs_to relationship and i guess that's the reason i was getting an error for the 3rd line of code but using '@answer = @question.build_answer' seems to be doing the job :). Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
@survey = Survey.new
@survey.question = Question.new
@survey.question.answer = Answer.new
@survey.question.answer = (whatever)
@survey.save!
```

(or just `@survey.save` if you don't want to see exceptions)

If you want to make it easier to access these as instance variables in your view you can assign any of them to a variable after you've created them, and the association will be maintained:

```
@question = @survey.question
```

It's up to you.